# MySQL error - creating table and trying current date as default

Tags: mysql

CREATE TABLE `payment`.`payment_details` (
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` INT NOT NULL,
`mode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`payment_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `payment`.`payment_details` (
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` INT NOT NULL,
`mode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`payment_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `payment`.`payment_details` (
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` INT NOT NULL,
`mode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`payment_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))

Answer (score 0):

> you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that, for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default

You can't set the default value on `DATE` type in MySQL, as per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).

You can use `TIMESTAMP` instead and set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value.

Comment: This appears to only be true for MySQL versions < 8. You could add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the mysql client:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version  for the right
> syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE,
> PRIMARY KEY (customer_id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5 ...

This is related to the invalid syntax in your column definition for the `payment_date`. The correct syntax would be:

```
payment_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE),
```

This worked fine with MySQL Server version 8.0.30.

The following two are just the same as above:

```
payment_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE()),
payment_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURDATE()),
```